# Routing issues in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In a WordPress site, some data is getting fetched from a folder 'uploads/slider' using http_get function. However,  the URL given in the function is 'ws/slider/list' and not 'upload/slider'.

Now, the app is migrated to another server and the http_get code is returning 404 even though data is present in uploads/slider folder. Is there any place where we have to set the routing logic? 
PS: I don't have experience in WordPress.

Comment: Did you able to access the site after the migration?

Comment: try to update your permalinks twice and then check again `Admin_Panel->Settings->Permalinks`

Comment: how did you migrated your database?
-make sure you use [wp-db-migrate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) plugin to export the database from your current server.
After installing wp db migrate , go to tools -> Db migrate -> add you migration url and new file path and than click on migrate db.
And try export this database to your new server.

Comment: @tzafar I don't have the super admin creds. With the creds I have I can't see the settings. Can you point me towards the exact location where these settings are added.  Like db table?

Comment: @gautam3164 Hi ra Gautam. Yes, site is working fine

Comment: `http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` login at the backend and enter above url. if you get access to the page then click twice on the `save changes` and then check

Comment: Ok Lets check your migrated url from DB once and manually change the permalink once through the panel

Comment: @tzafar No luck with direct URL.. Can we check the corresponding db table?

Comment: The db was exported and imported directly.. What are the implications if we don't use that migrate option?

Comment: WordPress itself does not do some magic uploads folder routing, that is probably added by the plugin handling that slider. You might want to take a look at the plugin code and/or .htaccess file in the installation folder.

Comment: why you try to to read from upload folder ... I think all the concept is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I've answered several questions of late that are similar to this. Often times migrating a database from one server to another will require serialization as the origin and destination have varying data string character counts.

> One solution is to perform a text based "search and replace" on the
>   database dump, but this is likely to result in lost data, because a
>   WordPress database likely includes serialized php objects, which are
>   strings PHP uses to store complex objects as text data. A serialized
>   string not only stores the value of a object but also its size (number
>   of characters) therefore if the old and the new domains or URLs have
>   different character counts, PHP will not be able to recreate the
>   original object anymore.

Try http://pixelentity.com/wordpress-search-replace-domain/